# Creating TFRecord file causes UnicodeDecodeError when being read

Tags: tensorflow, unicode, object-detection, tfrecord

I'm following the directions to create a TFRecord file in this example for object detection:

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/using_your_own_dataset.md

I have created a Jupyter Notebook with Python 3.6.4 and TensorFlow 1.6.0 with these instructions.

I changed the value assignment inside `create_tf_example` to enter the correct information from my example (which is a PIL Image):

```
def create_tf_example(example):
    height = example.height
    width = example.width
    filename = tf.compat.as_bytes(example.filename)

    # convert Image to bytes for TF
    imgByteArr = io.BytesIO()
    example.save(imgByteArr, format='PNG')
    imgByteArr = imgByteArr.getvalue()
    encoded_image_data = tf.compat.as_bytes(imgByteArr, encoding='utf-8') # Encoded image bytes

    image_format = b'png'

    xmins = [0]
    xmaxs = [width]
    ymins = [0]
    ymaxs = [height]

    classes_text = [b'Test']
    classes = [1] 

    tf_example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
        'image/height': dataset_util.int64_feature(height),
        'image/width': dataset_util.int64_feature(width),
        'image/filename': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename),
        'image/source_id': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename),
        'image/encoded': dataset_util.bytes_feature(encoded_image_data),
        'image/format': dataset_util.bytes_feature(image_format),
        'image/object/bbox/xmin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmins),
        'image/object/bbox/xmax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmaxs),
        'image/object/bbox/ymin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymins),
        'image/object/bbox/ymax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymaxs),
        'image/object/class/text': dataset_util.bytes_list_feature(classes_text),
        'image/object/class/label': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(classes),
    }))

    return tf_example
```

However, it will create the file without issue and when I try to read it again, I'm getting an error. This is the same error when I try to read the TFRecord file later with TensorFlow (`label_map_util.load_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS)`):

```
open('data/tfrecord/label_map.pbtxt').read()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-dfa57505da97> in <module>()
----> 1 open('data/tfrecord/label_map.pbtxt').read()

~/Documents/.../bin/../lib/python3.6/codecs.py in decode(self, input, final)
    319         # decode input (taking the buffer into account)
    320         data = self.buffer + input
--> 321         (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
    322         # keep undecoded input until the next call
    323         self.buffer = data[consumed:]

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbe in position 10: invalid start byte
```

It isn't clear to me what I should be doing differently because of `tf_example.SerializeToString()` seems to be doing the encoding to a string in the example.

Here is the output if it helps from `open('data/tfrecord/label_map.pbtxt', 'rb').read()`:

```
b'kX\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05@\xbe\xe0\n\xe7\xb0\x01\n\x15\n\x0bimage/width\x12\x06\x1a\x04\n\x02\x98\x03\n\x17\n\x0cimage/format\x12\x07\n\x05\n\x03png\n!\n\x18image/object/class/label\x12\x05\x1a\x03\n\x01\x01\n\x16\n\x0cimage/height\x12\x06\x1a\x04\n\x02\x98\x03\nM\n\x17image/object/class/text\x122\n0\n.Qma8oN1eQwAiKUQZJRXry1VD2yCwYWnZQ6rtQwsC8LzjDu\nR\n\x0fimage/source_id\x12?\n=\n;data/png/Qma8oN1eQwAiKUQZJRXry1VD2yCwYWnZQ6rtQwsC8LzjDu.png\n"\n\x16image/object/bbox/ymin\x12\x08\x12\x06\n\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\n\xf2\xac\x01\n\rimage/encoded\x12\xdf\xac\x01\n\xdb\xac\x01\n\xd7\xac\x01\x89PNG\r\n
```

Thank you!

Comment: I think you encoded a non ascii character. So just try reading it at byte level. open("filename", 'rb').read()

Comment: Ok, makes a lot of sense. How do I tell why the non-ASCII character is being created? TensorFlow is generating the file... This is what is output right now: "b'\xd4W\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00n\xe3$\xf5\n\xd0\xaf\x01\n\x14\n\x0bimage/width\x12..."